# Zend 1.12 + Ajax - Submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, zend-framework, twitter-bootstrap-3

After user clicks on submit form, I need to call Zend validation of that form without refreshing whole page. I also use zend_Layout in my website. I have seen a lot of tutorials here, but still cant make it working.

Index Controller:

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

    public function init() {

    }

    public function indexAction() {
$this->view->static_data = "eg. ABCDEFG"; 

        $this->view->form = new Application_Form_Test();
    }
    public function ajaxAction() {
        // probably some code to hande ajax 
    }
}
```

View for index/index:

```
...
<?php 
echo date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
echo $this->static_data; 
?>

<hr />
<?php echo $this->form ?>
...
```

Form:

```
class Application_Form_Test extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->setMethod('post');
        $this->setAttrib('class', 'form1');

        $this->addElement('text', 'email', array(
            'label'      => 'Your email address:',
            'required'   => true,
            'filters'    => array('StringTrim'),
            'validators' => array(
                'EmailAddress',
            )
        ));

        $this->addElement('text', 'name', array(
            'label'      => 'Your name:',
            'required'   => true,
            'validators' => array(
                array('validator' => 'StringLength', 'options' => array(3, 20))
                )
        ));

        // Add the submit button
        $this->addElement('submit', 'submit', array(
            'ignore'   => true,
            'label'    => 'Send',
        ));

        // And finally add some CSRF protection
        $this->addElement('hash', 'csrf', array(
            'ignore' => true,
        ));
    }
}
```

So how can i validate form without refreshing rest of that page and see Zend Error Messages in case that form is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can post the form to your Ajax action where you will instantiate the form and inject data from the request.

```
$form = new Form();
if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
    if ($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())) {
        //save data
        ....
    }
}
$this->view->form = $form;
```

You have two options:

- Render the form in the view and respond with HTML. Using JavaScript replace current form with HTML returned by the Ajax request.
- Get error messages using `Zend_Form::getMessages()` and respond with JSON.

  `$this-view->messages = $form->getMessages();`

Comment: Thanks, for advice, now I have solved it with code in my other Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28616995/zend-form-ajax-how-to-redirect